# Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: html, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twiiter bootstrap to generate a collapsable menu and I get an error while validating this code:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/outfits">Outfits</a></li>
    <li><a href="/champions">Champiopns</a></li>
    <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/users/sign_in">Login</a>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the error:

```
 Line 73, Column 12: Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
Contexts in which element li may be used:
Inside ol elements.
Inside ul elements.
Inside menu elements.
Content model for element div:
Flow content.
```

I don't understand, it looks to me that the li elements are properly wrapped inside an ul...

How do I make this code validate?

Comment: Validates fine for me: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @KevinBoucher, indeed it does. Anyway pasting the complete page still gives me this error. Can the problem be related to some parent div?

Comment: It's certainly possible that a broken tag elsewhere could cause this error message.

Comment: Yes, look for an unclosed tag elsewhere in the document.